# Mysql Not Working After El Capitan Upgrade

Tags: mysql, macos, macports, osx-elcapitan, mysql5

I recently upgraded my Mac Pro to a Mac Mini and used the migration assistant to transfer all my files and applications across to the Mac Mini.

I also re-installed macports and configured apache etc. So I've managed to get my localhost and php working on the new machine.

However I am now unable to start mysql from terminal?

When I try my usual:

```
mysql5 -u root -p;
```

and got the following error:

```
Error:  ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've also tried restarting mysql:

```
sudo opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server restart
```

and got the following error:

```
ERROR! Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.
```

When I navigate to my mysql5 directory /opt/local/var/db/mysql5/ I see a list of my databases, and see the following PID files:

```
myName.local.pid
```

and

```
localhost pid
```

So the structure is similar to what was on my old Mac but I confused as to what is causing mysql to not start?

Interestingly, mysql must be still working because when I run an .php scripts in my browser the mysql queries work and the data is being retrieved.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: download mysqlworkbench and fire up an admin session. It's pretty awful how Apple screws up your mysql install with that upgrade. signed ; burned badly.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED**

I would like to share the solution that I came across to resolve this issue.

When you update to El Capitan from a previous version of OSX your mysql settings get lost. When you try to connect via:

```
 mysql5 -u root -p;
```

I was getting the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

The problem was with my.cnf!

The default configuration of macports mysql does not come with a my.cnf (it does however have others my-medium.cnf, my-small.cnf) so the Macports mysql client is going to look where the Macports server is set to look.

I also learned that if you've changed the socket path away from the default then you need to tell everything where it is. Most programs have a hard coded default that can be overridden, I had overridden the macports default to the one php is compiled to, so you need to tell the client what you've changed it to otherwise how is it supposed to know.

Because I did not have a copy of my.cnf in opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql, the client did not know where to look for the socket.  So I had to define the path to the socket in the my.cnf for both the [client] and [mysqld] configurations.

The in my case the path to the socket should have been:

```
socket = /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock
```

I then restarted mysql:

```
sudo /opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server restart
```

And SUCCESS at last.

Hope this helps.